# Python: Trim a list

Tags: python, list, trim

I have this:

> Lt = [('ABC', ), ('Abc', ), ('xyz', ),
>   ('ABC', ), ('Abc', )]

I want this:

> Lt = ('Abc', 'Abc', 'xyz', 'ABC', 'ABc')

remove the extra "(",")" and ",".... How do i do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution:

```
r=zip(*Lt)[0]
print Lt
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it included some explanation of how this works, or what cases it applies to. Because it's not a general solution to how to "trim a list." Instead, it's a way to transform a list of tuples into a single tuple containing the first item of each of the original tuples.

Answer (score 5):

Is that a list of strings or tuples? Assuming they're tuples:

```
[t[0] for t in [('ABC', ), ('Abc', ), ('xyz', ), ('ABC', ), ('Abc', )]]
```

Comment: For the sake of learning, this is called a "list comprehension" and thy are very efficient and easy to do in Python!

Comment: It gives me the last ('Abc',) missing everything else

Comment: [('ABC',), ('Abc',), ('xyz',), ('ABC',), ('Abc',)]
>>> [t[0] for t in [('ABC', ), ('Abc', ), ('xyz', ), ('ABC', ), ('Abc', )]]
['ABC', 'Abc', 'xyz', 'ABC', 'Abc']

Comment: @user428862: Could you be mistyping something perhaps? Because the code does work (I just copied it into my Python shell to verify).

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
a = tuple([''.join(x) for x in Lt])

>>> a
('ABC', 'Abc', 'xyz', 'ABC', 'Abc')
```

Comment: You can remove the square brackets in the call to `tuple`. a generator expression suffices because `tuple` will consume it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
In [5]: tuple(map(operator.itemgetter(0), Lt))
Out[5]: ('ABC', 'Abc', 'xyz', 'ABC', 'Abc')
```